# Why different result between centos and macos to use curl command

Tags: curl, http2

Guy

I have a very strange problem, when i use curl to request https on my mac is succesful ,but when i request on centos is permission deny to return

mac curl -V :
curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0) libcurl/7.54.0 LibreSSL/2.6.5 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.24.1
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy

centos curl -V :

curl 7.65.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.65.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips zlib/1.2.7 nghttp2/1.24.0
Release-Date: 2019-05-22
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp sm

Comment: What's the entire command you're executing?

Comment: curl -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5341f Safari/604.1' https://www.retailmenot.com

Comment: The link retailmenot.com need to add https://

Comment: I get a `301` on both Cent and Mac OS, and so should you normally. Is it possible you just sent off too many requests or did something else to trigger their systems to block you?

Comment: I check anything，it still show me 403，may be the Server Ip address the website not allow，still thank u reply this !!!!!